# Getting Uncaught SyntaxError in JS scripts

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript. Suddenly getting the following syntax errors. Not sure from where it is coming.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Can you please help on this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I assume this is inside of a `<script>` tag, in which case the first `</script>` will end that tag, even if it is in a JavaScript comment or a string.

Comment: We dont have this code.. Not sure from where it is coming

Answer (score 0):

Remove `</script>` from your code. Since it is a `.js` file, you can't use script tags here. script tags are only allowed inside `html` files

Comment: Nope, the issue is, that the script "tags" are occurring in the comments of those files.

Comment: @Teemu That's so weird. Whatever browser he is using, it isn't rendering them as comments. At least, not all of them.

Comment: @Kirshnan_mon, may we know where(browser/editor) you are running your code?

Comment: It's not weird, it's rather a property of (even a bug?) in the HTML parsers, a parser parses script tags even inside the script text without considering how the tag is used in the script. Kinda understandable,  from the view of an HTML parser, script tags are just tags to not to show the content, a parser just tries to find the opening/closing tags like from any other element, it doesn't know the semantics of JS.

Comment: @Teemu Oh I see. I have never encountered this issue.

Comment: I am running on browser. After some deployment, we are getting the page but some code also printing at the bottom. Attached the screenshot for the same